# Running Multiple Webtests in VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing

I have just recently upgraded from VS2010 to VS2012 Ultimate. I have been running Web Performance tests and Load tests on this setup on 2010, but the biggest problem in 2012 is that they seemed to have removed any way to run all my Webtests at the same time. Since I no longer can use the test list editor, or even the test explorer, the only options I have been able to come up with are:

- Put all web tests into a load test, and run it just long enough for every test to be run once
- Use mstest in cmd
- Use the run all tests, stop the run, uncheck all load tests or other webtests I do not want to run, and then run the rest

However, the only method that has worked so far is the last one (though its a pain).

The 1st option could work, it just requires adding more virtual users and/or more time than I have had. The flaw with it is just inefficiency since I only want to run each one only once and then stop.

As for the cmd line solution, I am not sure why this is not working. For some reason they always error when trying to load the assembly that contains my custom plugins (Error: "Could not load file or assembly.."). The command I use (in solution dir): 'mstest /testcontainer:"LoadTest\Workstation\NormalOrder\Order1.webtest" /testsettings:Main.testsettings'

I am just looking for any solution to this problem that would work the best. Ideally the webtests would show in the Test Explorer, but until that happens, I will continue to run with my 3rd option.

EDIT:

Followup to answer below.

[image: Selecting 2 of 4 tests]
[image: All 4 tests were run]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can run multiple web tests in the same time  ; it's just different in VS2012.

First, select desired web tests in the solution explorer and then, from the `LOAD TEST` menu, choose `Run` or `Debug` and then chose either `Selected Test`.

[image: web tests]

Comment: That looks like it should work.. Is there a reason why it would not work when I try it.

Comment: I marked this as the answer. It does not seem to work at the moment, but I think this is the intended functionality, and hopefully it will work in the future.